# Generate a image of QRCode for Android

Tags: android, qr-code

In my app,I want to create a image of QRCode shows on my Android screen (Without internet access).
currently I know how to code the barcode scanner in my app, here the code for my scanner

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

however I also need to generate the QRCode image, I have research a bit, and got this(totally no idea how to code, I am just a learner><)

```
com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder
```

Can someone show me how to generate a image of QRCode for Android, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method that will encode for you.

```
private void encodeBarcode(String type, String data) {
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
  intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

here is an example usage

```
     encodeBarcode("TEXT_TYPE", "http://androidninja.me");
```

The [ZXingTestActivity.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/androidtest/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidtest/ZXingTestActivity.java) contains some more examples, including all of the options for type.